# Олимпиадная задача. Максимально возможное число

Tags: комбинаторика, олимпиада

Здравствуйте. Я прошу привести названия алгоритма (алгоритмов) и желательно источники, которые помогут разобраться в решении следующей задачи:

Условия задачи полностью:

> Bom has a list of n favorite numbers which are birthday, driving license, passport number, etc After creating an email account, Bom wants to choose a password as the largest number P among all possible numbers generated by the combinations of k (1 <= k <= n) positive numbers in the favorite list so that P is divisible by 9.
>
> Your task is writing a program to help find P the password for Bom’s email.
>
> Input
>
> The first line contains a positive integer T as the number of test cases in the input file. The
>   following lines describe information of each test case including:
>   • One line containing two positive integers n and k,
>   • n following lines are n favorite numbers.
>
> Output
>
> The output file contains T lines; each line is the solution of the corresponding test case that is
>   either password P or -1 in case of not finding a feasible number.

Я сначала думал решить комбинаторикой (через сочетания), но это затратно по времени, да и перебор в лоб достаточно трудоёмкий. Так, если чисел 100, а надо выбрать 50, то необходимо перебрать:  1.0089134454556E+29 комбинаций.

Да ещё один вариант, который я попытался реализовать работал так:

1) сортируем список чисел по убыванию;

2) берём верхнее (с удалением);

3) ищем ему пару, чтобы при конкатенации была делимость на 9 без остатка;

4) если пара есть и есть место добавляем в список ответа;

5) если пара есть, но нет места пытаемся убрать из ответа 2 числа так, чтобы получилось при подстановки пары число больше, и делящееся на 9 без остатка;

6) если пары нет, то просто забываем о числе и переходим на пункт 2.

7) когда числа кончились если в размер списка чисел с ответами равен необходимому, то выводим их;

8) если нет, то -1, такого числа нет.

Но в таком алгоритме есть проблема, например числа 7 1 1, при конкатенации делятся на 9, но они просто удаляться.

Какой алгоритм может помочь при решении данной задачи?

Comment: Конкатенацию можно заменить сложением. Вроде.

Comment: Попробуйте динамическое программирование по трем параметрам - числу возможных элементов, длине конкатенации и остатку от деления конкатенации на 9.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov, по условию числа можно только конкатенировать, как строки. Это ведь олимпиадная задача.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, можно более конкретнее? Не совсем понял в какую сторону смотреть

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: @МаксимДробышев, тогда следовало бы привести условие полностью. Если оно и приведено в вопросе, то там ничего нет про то, что числа можно только конкатенировать. Задача другая - найти число. Если числа при конкатенации дают число, делящееся на 9, то они и при сложении дают число, делящееся на 9, и в обратную сторону.

Comment: @PavelMayorov напоминает чем-то задачу о ранце. То есть есть максимальный объем ранца - m. Есть то что туда можно положить - числа, и у этих чисел есть характеристика - сумма цифр. Добавляем в ранец пока не полный, и если когда он полный сумма сумм (простите за тавтологию) делиться на 9 без остатка, то это хороший рюкзак и сохраняем эти числа.

Comment: @МаксимДробышев нет, не так. Надо на каждом этапе рассматривать 10 вариантов с разными остатками, а в конце выбрать тот где остаток 0.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а откуда появилось число 10?

Comment: @МаксимДробышев Ну, ошибся. Там надо читать 9.

Comment: @МаксимДробышев, все еще не видно, почему нельзя заменить конкатенацию сложением при проверке делимости на 9. Асимптотически сложение вроде не быстрее, но это поддерживаемая аппаратно операция, то есть в константе будет очень существенный выигрыш. А в конце можете соединить полученный набор чисел конкатенацией.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov, я говоря о конкатенации говорил о выводе на консоль. Хотя пожалуй да, надо отредактировать,  звучит двусмысленно. Я делал проверку на делимость именно суммируя суммы цифр.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а то есть мы перебираем, но перебираем сразу в 9 потоков?

Comment: @МаксимДробышев **нет**

Comment: @PavelMayorov тогда я не понял, что Вы имеете ввиду под _на каждом этапе рассматривать 10 вариантов с разными остатками_. Скажем чисел у нас 25 надо 13, тогда комбинаций: 5200300. И как из них выбрать 9 или 10?

Comment: @МаксимДробышев как в условии задачи написано.

Comment: Блин, прочитайте уже что такое динамическое программирование.

Comment: @PavelMayorov я читал, я знаю что это. Я просто не могу разработать или найти алгоритм на последнюю задачу. Вы говорите общими фразами, не привязываясь к конкретному алгоритму, поэтому я не могу Вас понять.

Comment: @МаксимДробышев значит, либо вы не знаете что это такое, либо читаете невнимательно. К алгоритму я не привязываюсь намеренно - времени нет.

Answer (score -1):

Сортируем числа по убыванию, одновременно рассчитываем их длину и остаток от деления на 9.

Затем (ветви и границы, в порядке убывания) набираем заданное количество чисел так, чтобы их совокупность (конкатенация, сумма, сумма остатков - это однофигственно) делилась на 9. Считаем получившуюся суммарную длину. Именно такая суммарная длина должна получиться у результата.

Далее полным перебором просматриваем все варианты наборов с заданным количеством чисел, дающих только что полученную суммарную длину. Каждый набор конкатенируем в порядке убывания чисел при выравнивании по левому краю.

Максимальный результат и есть искомый.

Comment: Длина результирующего подмножества и есть m. Она сразу строго задана. То есть в результате, не может быть больше m чисел.

Comment: @МаксимДробышев А я что-то другое сказал? _просматриваем все варианты наборов **с заданным количеством чисел**_ - неужели эту фразу можно понять иначе?

Comment: А каким образом мы набираем кол-во чисел, так, чтобы их совокупность делилась на 9? Просто перебором всех чисел вообще или только заданных? И суммарную длину чего считать? Если есть статья по этому алгоритму (даже лучше если на английском) можете отправить?

Comment: `каким образом мы набираем кол-во чисел, так, чтобы их совокупность делилась на 9?` Да перебором. Наша задача на этом этапе - найти ЛЮБУЮ совокупность, чтобы её сумма делилась на 9, а суммарная длина была максимально возможной. Просто перебор у нас сильно ограничен снизу. Если m-e число имеет длину k - то перебираем только в рамках чисел длиной не менее k. И только в случае, когда не набрали - начинаем перебор в рамках чисел длиной не менее k-1. Для того и считалась длина чисел в штуках цифр.